# I tried to intsall etherpad, after it my ubuntu 20.04 booting very slow. it taking too much time to boot

Tags: boot

I tried to install etherpad, but it wasn't successful but after that my ubuntu 20.04 booting very slow, it taking too much time to boot. if I see system analyse time with `$ systemd-analyze time` It is showing like

````
Startup finished in 3.852s (kernel) + 1min 36.385s (userspace) = 1min 40.237s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 36.375s in userspace```How can I fix this and make to boot fast as before. `systemd-analyze blame`  results as 1min 34.672s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
      6.332s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
      5.805s fwupd.service                                        
      5.035s bolt.service                                         
      1.326s jenkins.service                                      
       924ms snapd.service                                        
       856ms snap-snapd-12057.mount                               
       850ms snap-udemy-21.mount                                  
       829ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-72.mount               
       774ms snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-238.mount                  
       701ms gdm.service                                          
       577ms snap-snap\x2dstore-518.mount                         
       576ms snap-snapd-11841.mount                               
       575ms dev-loop0.device                                     
       546ms snap-core-11167.mount                                
       543ms docker.service                                       
       536ms snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-240.mount                  
       470ms dev-loop3.device                                     
       467ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount              
       463ms dev-loop2.device                                     
       452ms dev-loop4.device                                     
       449ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-128.mount              
       398ms snap-core-11081.mount                                
       391ms dev-loop1.device                                     
       388ms snap-openboard-14.mount                              
       387ms dev-loop5.device                                     
       386ms dev-loop6.device                                     
       373ms dev-nvme0n1p5.device                                 
       322ms snapd.seeded.service                                 
       283ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service  
       279ms dev-loop8.device                                     
       279ms snap-snap\x2dstore-542.mount                         
       265ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1515.mount              
       246ms mariadb.service                                      
       216ms systemd-resolved.service                             
       205ms networkd-dispatcher.service                          
       191ms dev-loop9.device                                     
       191ms dev-loop7.device                                     
       189ms apparmor.service                                     
       173ms systemd-timesyncd.service                            
       162ms snap-core18-2066.mount                               
       160ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-66.mount               
       159ms containerd.service                                   
       150ms systemd-logind.service                               
       149ms etherpad.service                                     
       147ms ua-messaging.service                                 
       144ms accounts-daemon.service                              
       144ms dev-loop14.device                                    
       142ms dev-loop12.device                                    
       135ms snap-core18-1997.mount                               
       134ms udisks2.service                                      
       123ms dev-loop13.device                                    
       122ms user@125.service                                     
       114ms dev-loop11.device                                    
       114ms dev-loop10.device                                    
       110ms user@126.service                                     
       109ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount              
       108ms upower.service                                       
       105ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                         
        95ms user@1000.service                                    
        89ms systemd-journal-flush.service                        
        89ms keyboard-setup.service                               
        83ms systemd-journald.service                             
        82ms polkit.service                                       
        80ms dev-loop15.device                                    
        79ms avahi-daemon.service                                 
        72ms NetworkManager.service                               
        70ms ModemManager.service                                 
        68ms iio-sensor-proxy.service                             
        66ms nginx.service                                        
        66ms switcheroo-control.service                           
        59ms systemd-udevd.service                                
        58ms apport.service                                       
        52ms thermald.service                                     
        51ms lm-sensors.service                                   
        49ms wpa_supplicant.service                               
        48ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                       
        47ms gpu-manager.service                                  
        44ms open-fprintd.service                                 
        44ms grub-common.service                                  
        43ms colord.service                                       
        43ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0E0A\x2dC8A2.service
        42ms smartmontools.service                                
        42ms ssh.service                                          
        36ms e2scrub_reap.service                                 
        35ms snapd.apparmor.service                               
        34ms secureboot-db.service                                
        31ms teamviewerd.service                                  
        29ms dev-loop16.device                                    
        27ms systemd-modules-load.service                         
        25ms user-runtime-dir@125.service                         
        24ms systemd-update-utmp.service                          
        22ms alsa-restore.service                                 
        20ms rsyslog.service                                      
        20ms systemd-sysusers.service                             
        20ms swapfile.swap                                        
        19ms systemd-random-seed.service                          
        19ms modprobe@drm.service                                 
        18ms boot-efi.mount                                       
        18ms bluetooth.service                                    
        18ms systemd-sysctl.service                               
        17ms plymouth-start.service                               
        17ms systemd-rfkill.service                               
        16ms systemd-remount-fs.service                           
        16ms systemd-backlight@leds:tpacpi::kbd_backlight.service 
        14ms plymouth-read-write.service                          
        13ms dev-hugepages.mount                                  
        13ms dev-mqueue.mount                                     
        12ms kmod-static-nodes.service                            
        12ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                               
        12ms ufw.service                                          
        12ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                             
        11ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                       
        11ms pppd-dns.service                                     
        11ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
        10ms user-runtime-dir@126.service                         
        10ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                        
         9ms kerneloops.service                                   
         9ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                   
         8ms systemd-user-sessions.service                        
         8ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                 
         8ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                        
         7ms sysstat.service                                      
         7ms setvtrgb.service                                     
         7ms sys-kernel-config.mount                              
         5ms console-setup.service                                
         4ms openvpn.service                                      
         4ms dev-loop17.device                                    
         1ms rtkit-daemon.service                                 
       961us docker.socket                                        
       523us snapd.socket```
````

Comment: Desktop or Server installation? How long does it take to boot? Was it slow before you tried to install Etherpad? What kind of hardware?

Comment: Hey @heynnema Thank you for the response.. on the desktop. It taking 2mints to boot. before it was very fast.

Comment: What went wrong when you tried to install Etherpad? Were you able to successfully able to uninstall it? You didn't say Desktop or Server installation, or type of hardware. HDD or SSD? Processor? Etc.

Comment: What command was used to install Etherpad? Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *ether*` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.